# How to extract string from link in JSON response body; POSTMAN

Tags: json, string, postman, extract

i want to extract last string from _links.scaStatus.href which is: d186b5de-f05e-43ac-9924-c3f504e81291

```
{
    "consentStatus": "received",
    "consentId": "12da0088-f48b-4a87-9d9b-29cd66de0825",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/consents/12da0088-f48b-4a87-9d9b-29cd66de0825"
        },
        "status": {
            "href": "/consents/12da0088-f48b-4a87-9d9b-29cd66de0825/status"
        },
        "scaStatus": {
            "href": "/consents/12da0088-f48b-4a87-9d9b-29cd66de0825/authorisations/d186b5de-f05e-43ac-9924-c3f504e81291"
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Tests tab in your requests and collections to write tests that will execute when Postman receives a response from the API you sent the request to.

You can write test scripts for your Postman API requests in JavaScript([see this](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/test-scripts/)). There are many example in [Test script examples](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/#parsing-response-body-data).

For your example use this:

```js
const responseJson = pm.response.json();
var test = responseJson._links.scaStatus.href;
//var test = "/consents/12da0088-f48b-4a87-9d9b-29cd66de0825/authorisations/d186b5de-f05e-43ac-9924-c3f504e81291";
 var arr = test.split("/");
console.log(arr[4]);
```